# Disable Outlook Reminders Per Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, notifications, reminder

Is it possible to disable reminders for individual calendars in Outlook? I am happy to retain my default settings for my "base" Calendar, but for my custom Calendar, I want to suppress all reminders.

[image]

Comment: When setting up calendar items there is the option to turn off reminders. Would that work?

Comment: No, that's per item, not per calendar.